# Authentication using SAML

Tags: authentication, saml-2.0

My client asked me to develop a web api and use SAML as authentication.

I came across with the image below from this [site](https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2013/05/09/choosing-an-sso-strategy-saml-vs-oauth2/), that shows the authentication flow.

However I don't know how to use the token that is generated after the authentication.

- Do I need to store it as any other session variable?
- Do I have to renew the `token` after a certain time or it lasts during all the session?

**Note:** The authorization server / idP is maintained by other party.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you develop the web API yourself, there's no need to refresh the token.

You're API needs to be added as relying party to the IdP. After that you can redirect to the IdP and initiate authentication. The token you get back contains several attributes (also configurable on the IdP) like unique user-id (uid), e-mail, name, country, etc...

In most cases this token is signed using a public/private key. Your API server needs to verify the signature, the issuer (the IdP), the audience (your API) of the token and consume the attributes. When everything is OK, you'll need to provision a local user account, link the external uid and create a local authentication cookie (or generate a OAuth2 token if your API uses OAUth2 or OpenIdConnect) for the locally provisioned user account.

Since this is a complex process, depending on the language/framework you're using, you might want to look into existing implementations.

Comment: So basically, I need to have a public certificate to ensure the authenticity of the token and if(valid){ do things} else {return 401/3} on my Web API, right?

Comment: yes, you need the public certificate or just the thumbprint of the certificate as the public certificate itself is included in the SAML assertion. See [some examples](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php)